# $j∈R$ and $256(1-λ(1-λ))^3-j λ^2(1-λ)^2＝0$ implies $λ∈R$ and $λ$ is not congruent to $0$ or $1$ mod $M$

Tags: ring-theory, elliptic-curves, local-field

Let $K$ be a local field whose residue field's is not characteristic $2$, and $R$ be it's ring of integers, and $M$ be $R$'s maximal ideal. Let $j∈R$, then,

I would like to prove $256(1-λ(1-λ))^3-j λ^2(1-λ)^2＝0$ implies **$λ∈R$** and $λ$ is not congruent to $0$ or $1$ mod $M$.

The latter part is obvious, because if $λ$ is congruent to $0$ or $1$, $256＝0$ does not hold in it's residue field.

But I'm stuck with proving **$λ∈R$**.

Silverman reads we use **integrality of $j$**, but I don't see how to do it.

Thank you in advance.

This is a question from Silverman's 'the arithmetic of elliptic curves', $p199$.

P.S

$v(j)＝0$ implies $3v(1-λ(1-λ))＝2v(λ)＋2c(1-λ)$, but I cannot proceed from here.

Comment: I think you should be able to show using valuations that if $\lambda \notin R$ then $j \notin R$.

Comment: Apply the valuation to both sides of $256(1 - \lambda(1 - \lambda))^3 = j\lambda^2(1 - \lambda)^2$. Assume that $\lambda \notin R$, i.e. $v(\lambda) < 0$. Express $v(j)$ in terms of $v(\lambda)$ and conclude that $v(j) < 0$, which is a contradiction as $j \in R$ means $v(j) \geq 0$ (not necessarily $v(j) = 0$, this means that $j$ is a unit in the ring of integers)